# Fullsimplify not working perfectly

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-form

Here I am using the below code for a simplification.

```
DB = σ*σ*ϕ*ϕ
    BB = Sqrt[DB] // FullSimplify // PowerExpand
    g = 1/DB
   
    αI = aϕ
    α = αI - 0.5*BB*D[BB, ϕ]
    αs = α - ((1/2)*BB*D[BB, ϕ])
    UG = 0.375 σ^2
    Phi = UG - ((1/2)*(g*αs*αs)) // FullSimplify // 
      PowerExpand
```

But I am getting a result without cancelling the common term $$\phi $$
Below is what I am getting. But I need to cancel the common terms. Here $$a, \sigma $$are constants. $$\phi$$ is a variable

Result I got:

[image: res]

Comment: @xzczd I think you might know this

Comment: Look at the assignment `\[Alpha]I = a\[Phi]`. Did you mean `\[Alpha]I = a*\[Phi]`?

Comment: Your @ doesn't work because I haven't yet appeared under this post… As to usage of @ , you may want to read this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/284701

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write aϕ, then this is interpreted as one single variable. You need to put a space between a and ϕ. With:

```
DB = σ*σ*ϕ*ϕ
BB = Sqrt[DB] // FullSimplify // PowerExpand
g = 1/DB

αI = a  ϕ
α = αI - 0.5*BB*D[BB, ϕ]
αs = α - ((1/2)*BB*D[BB, ϕ])
UG = 0.375 σ^2
Phi = UG - ((1/2)*(g*αs*αs)) // FullSimplify // PowerExpand
```

you then get:

> 1. a - (0.5 a^2)/σ^2 - 0.125 σ^2